# Find and Replace using IF condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, replace, find, vba

Right now I am using below macro to replace values in my large data. But the problem is, The replace or replaced values are changing with every data set and if required value not found the macro give error. Can anyone help me, how I use **IF** condition with **Cells.replace**. For example **IF**  **D** found then run this block of code otherwise jump to next value.

```
Sub ReplaceAll()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A1").Select

Cells.replace what:="D", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Cells.replace what:="F", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't get an error when the search term isn't found...

Comment: Same, no error triggered

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why errors should occur, but you could skip all errors.

```
Sub ReplaceAll()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error Resume Next 'Skip errors

Sheets("Data").Select
With Range("A1")
  .Cells.replace what:="D", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

  .Cells.replace what:="F", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End With

On Error Goto 0 'Errors will be handled again
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

But a better solution would be to handle your errors.
See [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) for information about [Error handling in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)

Also, you should try to avoid using `Select`, because it will slow down your macro an awful lot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I use the word error wrong. From error I mean that scenario changed every time with new data set. Most of the time my data is related to digite end with alphabet like `1600D` I want something like macor find the value, if found than replace it with whatever value I already stored in the macro, and if value not found go to next block of code.